# CPU utilization in SDN POX Controller

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ddos, pox

i have developed a DDOS Mitigation application in POX controller.
i would like to measure CPU USAGE during Attack when there is not any mitigation application and also when my mitigation application is running. (maybe it is a simple question in Linux but i am not master in Linux).
i want to prove that my application has improved CPU utilization during attack.
how can i do that?
i have seen some papers that have these kind of Results but do not know how to do the same.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal first shh connect to your VM

```
ssh -X mininet@192.168.56.102
```

Then get all the running processes pids

```
ps aux | less
```

You are interested of the pids your mininet hosts and switches and controllers are running, so search for similar lines like below

```
root      1462  0.0  0.0  21340  2048 pts/2    Ss+  14:04   0:00 bash --norc -is mininet:c0
root      1469  0.0  0.0  21340  2040 pts/3    Ss+  14:04   0:00 bash --norc -is mininet:h1
root      1473  0.0  0.0  21340  2044 pts/5    Ss+  14:04   0:00 bash --norc -is mininet:h2
root      1478  0.0  0.0  21336  2036 pts/6    Ss+  14:04   0:00 bash --norc -is mininet:s1
```

The second column are the pids. Let's say that I want to monitor the CPU usage of h1 before and while the attack. Just run in the terminal

```
top -p 1469
```

where 1469 is the desired pid. Leave this terminal open to monitor h1 CPU usage.