# Cpu and memory utilisation of individual host in mininet network topology

Tags: load, cpu-usage, host, sdn, mininet

Mininet hosts have their own network namespace, however, they all run in the same "process id namespace".

I want to know information (memory and cpu usage) regarding host-specific processes because I am experimenting with load balancing and I want to be able to gather some load metrics for each server (running on mininet hosts).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644275/cpu-utilization-in-sdn-pox-controller

Answer (score 0):

try to use this: [Mininet plot_cpu.py](https://github.com/mininet/mininet-util/blob/master/plot_cpu.py)!

Please, let me know if this information was useful.

Comment: Posting a link doesn't answer the question. Yo need to provide an explanation or more context.

Comment: Do you understand how to do this? I have the same problem